# How do I get a random number with a negative number in range?

Tags: java, random

Consider the following code:

```
int rand = new Random().nextInt((30 - 20) + 1) + 20
```

It will return a random number between 30 and 20. However, I need its range to include negative numbers. How would I include negative numbers in the generation?

I have tried using math that would be negative, but that resulted in an error. Simply subtracting or adding the negative numbers would not yield the desired value.

---

Sorry, I am only half awake. The correct code is `int rand = new Random().nextInt((30 - 20) + 1) + 20;`.

Comment: "It will return a random number between 30 and 20" - nope...

Comment: @alfasin I was going to say the same thing. Also, OP what range is the range of numbers you're looking to have?

Comment: Let me assure you that `(30 - 20) + 1` is just `11`.

Comment: @PM77-1 Except, as in this case, when it's `11` (exclusive) or `10` (inclusive).

Comment: *Simply subtracting or adding the negative numbers would not yield the desired value.* Technically true, it yields a desired range. What is the desired range?

Comment: 30 - -10. I'm trying to make a survival simulator. That will be my temperature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363681/608639)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To get a random number between a set range with `min` and `max`:

```
int number = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
```

It also works with negative numbers.

So:

```
random.nextInt(30 + 10) - 10;
// max = 30; min = -10;
```

Will yield a random int between -10 and 30 (exclusive).

It also works with doubles.

Comment: Doesn't work when the range `max-min` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: @awwsmm you can cast it to a long or something

Comment: Returns numbers out of range when negative.

Answer (score 16):

You can use Random.nextBoolean() to determine if it's a random positive or negative integer.

```
int MAX = 30;
Random random = new Random(); // Optionally, you can specify a seed, e.g. timestamp.
int rand = random.nextInt(MAX) * (random .nextBoolean() ? -1 : 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay. First, try to only create the `Random` instance once, but for an example,

```
int rand = -15 + new Random().nextInt(31);
```

is the range -15 to 15.

The [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) JavaDoc says (in part) *Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)*. Note that your provided example of `(30 - 20) + 1` is the range 0 to 10 (inclusive).

As a further example, to get the range 20 to 30 you would use:

```
int rand = 20 + new Random().nextInt(11);
```

Remember, the bounds of the result of is 0 to `n`.

> 30 - -10. I'm trying to make a survival simulator. That will be my temperature.

Ok. Let's write that range as `-10` to `30`. `nextInt(n)` will return a value between `0` and `n`, so if you want the range below 0 you must subtract `10` from the result and add `10` to the `n`. That's

```
Random random = new Random();
int rand = random.nextInt(41) - 10;
```

Now let's examine how we can determine those numbers. Remember, `nextInt()` will return between `0` and `n` (exclusive) and we want `-10` to `30` (inclusive); so `41` is `n` and we subtract `10`. If the result is `0` (the min) we get `-10`, if the result is `40` (the max) we get `30`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomNumber=(random.nextInt(DOUBLE_MAX)-MAX);
```

Alternatively, create a random positive or negative 1 and multiply it.